# Definability of a set

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm learning logic so please help me check these questions. In particular, I got stuck at number $6$ and $7$.

Let $L=\{ \cdot \}$ and let $M$ be the L-structyure whose underlying set is $\mathbb{N}$ (the nonnegative integers) and where the binary function $\cdot$ is interpreted as the multiplication.

1) Show that there is a formula $\phi_0[x]$ such that $M \vDash \phi_0[x]$ if and only if $a=0$.

**Attempt:** $\phi_0[x]=\forall y(y\cdot x \simeq x)$

2) Show that there is a formula $\phi_1[x]$ such that $M \vDash \phi_1[x]$ if and only if $a=1$.

**Attempt:** $\phi_1[x]=\forall y(y\cdot x \simeq y)$

3) Show that there is a formula $\phi_{prime}[x]$ such that $M\vDash \phi_{prime}[a]$ if and only if $a$ is prime.

**Attempt:** A prime number $p$ is a number that has only two distinct divisors, $1$ and $p$. So first I define division: $\tau[u,v] = \exists k(u\cdot k = v)$, and this formula is to be understood as $u | v$. Then I define $\phi_{prime}[x]= \forall y((\neg (y \simeq \phi_1[x]) \wedge \neg(y\simeq x) \rightarrow \neg \tau[y,x])$.

4) Show that if an automorphism $\sigma$ of $M$ satisfies $\sigma(p) = p$ for all prime numbers $p$, then $\sigma$ is the identity.

**Attempt:** We use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then write $n= p_1^{e_1}...p_s^{e_s}$. Then $\sigma(n)=\sigma(p_1^{e_1}...p_s^{e_s})= (\sigma(p_1))^{e_1}...(\sigma(p_s))^{e_s}=p_1^{e_1}...p_s^{e_s}=n$, and so $\sigma$ is the identity.

5)Find all automorphisms of $M$.

**Attempt:** The claim is that the identity is the unique automorphism of $M$. By (3), all primes are definable in $(\mathbb{N}, \cdot)$, and any automorphism fixes them. By (4), the automorphism is the identity map.

6) Show that the only two elements of $M$ such that there exists a formula $\phi_n$ such that $M \vDash \phi_n[a]$ if and only if $a=n$ are $0$ and $1$.

**Attempt**: Isn't this a contradiction because of (3)? I don't understand the difference between (3) and (6). Could someone please help me explain and give me a hint how to solve it?

7) Show that there is no formula $\psi[x,y,z]$ such that $M \vDash \psi[a,b,c]$ if and only if $c=a+b$.

**Attempt:** I scratched my head for an hour and couldn't see any direction...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 6 is the claim "The only elements $n$ for which the set $\{ n \}$ is definable are $n = 0$ and $n = 1$.". 3 is the claim "The set of all prime numbers is definable." There is no contradiction between these two claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1), (2), (3), and (4) are correct.

However, there is one big problem, which occurs both in your puzzlement with (3) vs. (6), and in your answer to (5): the distinction between a *set* of elements being definable, and *individual elements* being definable.

Just because a set of elements (like, the set of primes) is definable, does *not* mean that each (or even any!) of its *elements* is definable. For example, the whole domain of a structure is always definable (via "$x=x$"), but surely you don't believe that *every element* of a structure is always definable!

(If you prefer to talk about definable sets instead of definable elements, note that an element is definable iff its singleton is a definable set. So, the point is: just because a set is definable, does not mean that all its subsets are definable!)

This resolves the tension between (3) and (6). It also means your answer to (5) is wrong. Indeed, I claim that there are lots of automorphisms! HINT: think about what happens if you "permute" the primes . . .

---

Meanwhile, for (7), here's a hint: remember that the truth value of a formula on a tuple can't be changed by applying an automorphism to that tuple. So, for example, consider the instance "$2+3=5$" of the putative formula $\varphi$: do you see how to construct an automorphism $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(2)+\alpha(3)\not=\alpha(5)$?

---

Re: (7), note that the answer I outlined above is a **coarse** analysis: basically, we're saying that all formulas are "automorphism-invariant," so any property which is *not* invariant under automorphisms can't be defined by a formula. However, this isn't sharp: there are lots of times where we have an automorphism-invariant property which is not defined by a formula!

For example, if we consider the structure consisting of the natural numbers with *addition only* *(instead of multiplication only - the theory of this is called [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), while that of the structure you're considering in the OP is [Skolem arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_arithmetic))*, then there are no nontrivial automorphisms (exercise), so *every* relation is automorphism-invariant. On the other hand, there are only countably many definable relations, but uncountably many relations total (exercise), so clearly "most" relations are undefinable. (For example, it turns out multiplication is not definable!) How can we prove this?

In such cases a finer analysis is needed: one standard tool here is [**quantifier elimination**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_elimination), and another is [**Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game). But this is a very different topic, so I'll stop here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I understand definability now much better than before. Also your comment for (7) is very very interesting. Here are my attempts for the questions that I missed. Please help me check and give some feedback: For (5), the claim is that all automorphisms are just permutations of the prime numbers. By FTA, it's enough to analyze on the primes. Then since we showed in (3) that the set of primes is definable, so $\sigma$ fixes this set, i.e., $\sigma(p_i)=p_j$, for some prime $p_j$. Is this enough to prove (5)?

Comment: @HuyTruong Well, you need to show not just that $\sigma$ maps each prime to a prime, but also that each prime is in the image of $\sigma$. But that's not too hard.

Comment: For (6): if $n=0$ or $1$, then as showed in (1) and (2), we are done. For $n > 1$, by FTA, we can write n as a product of primes. Consider an autormorphism that shift every prime to the next prime right after it. Then clearly, $\sigma(n) \neq n$, in fact $(\sigma(n) > n$. Hence for $n > 1$, there is no formula $\phi_n[x]$ such that $M \vDash \phi_n[a]$.

Comment: For (7), consider an automorphism such that $\sigma(2) = 3$, $\sigma(3) = 5$, and $\sigma(5) = 7$ and keeps other primes fixed. Then $\sigma(2) + \sigma(3) \neq \sigma(7)$. And this completes the proof.

Comment: @NoahSchweberDo you mean the the following: let $\sigma$ be a map from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that it permutes the prime. Then I want to show that it is an automorphism by showing it's a monomorphism and also a surjective map? So for a $p_j$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ (on the right hand side), it is an image of $p_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ on the left hand side) because I defined in the beginning that $\sigma$ is a permutation that maps $p_i$ to some $p_j$. So we have the complete proof. Is this thinking correct?

Comment: @HuyTruong That's not quite correct - e.g. $\sigma$ can permute primes but still fail to be an automorphism by not respecting "$*$" (e.g. maybe $\sigma$ fixes every number except $4$ and $8$, and it swaps those). So the right condition is that $\sigma$ is *induced by* a permutation of primes - you start with a permutation $\pi$ of the primes, and then extend it in the "obvious" way (think about how to do this). Also, I think you mean "$\mathbb{N}$" instead of "$\mathbb{Z}$" but that's a minor point.

Comment: Basically, you want to show that there's a bijection between "automorphisms of $M$" and "permutations of the primes". So this has two directions: (1) every automorphism of $M$ permutes the primes, and (2) every permutation of the primes extends to an automorphism of $M$. Does this make things clearer?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll think about how to do it. But apart from (5), are (6) and (7) correct?

Comment: @HuyTruong Yes, 6 and 7 are right.

Comment: Hey Noah, thanks for your help. I was able to figure out  all the questions and wrote some thing that I felt confident. Actually my (6) and (7) above were both incorrect but I was able to fix them. Things finally start to make sense. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Noah, if possible, could you please have a look at my other post? It's this one: Huy Truong (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/278054/huy-truong), Induction on formulas in First Order Languages, URL (version: 2016-10-03): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1952450... I find that your explanation fits me really well and save me a lot of time when I'm trying to understand the main points of the exercise. Thanks for your time!